# Function to take a string from a cell and compare it to perform an action

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get a simple function working where I want the script to compare an excel cell that can only have two options of strings "INSERIR" or "IGNORAR" and make the interface switch to one sheet or another.
I am new to Google Sheets and Javascript.

Here is my code:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var source_cell = spreadsheet.getRange("C3");

if (source_cell == 'INSERIR') {
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('INSERIR ORÇAMENTO 1'), true);
} else {
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MENU PRINCIPAL'), true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

The current approach compares a [range object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) (the result of `getRange`) to a `string`.

**Solution:**

You need to [get the value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) of cell `C3`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source_cell = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("C3").getValue();
  if (source_cell == 'INSERIR') {
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('INSERIR ORÇAMENTO 1'), true);
  } 
  else if (source_cell == 'IGNORAR') {
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MENU PRINCIPAL'), true);
  }
}
```

**Note:**

- If you apply `getRange` directly to the `spreadsheet` object, you will get the value `C3` of the currently active sheet. If this is what you want, then fine. However, I recommend you get the sheet by its name so your code does not depend on the active sheet.
- Change `Sheet1` to the sheet name where `C3` has the value you would like to get.
- I use an `else if` statement because your current code will switch to `MENU PRINCIPAL` if the value is **different** from `INSERIR` but as far as I understand you want to switch to `MENU PRINCIPAL` only when `C3` is `IGNORAR`.